# How to customize datetime format with to_formatted_s in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm trying to have my datetime object display a specific way.
I like how

```
event.mytimeobject.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)
```

displays as: "Mon, 24 Aug 2015 00:00:00 +0000"

**Except** for the "00:00:00 +0000"

I'm trying to have it display as: "Mon, 24 Aug 2015"

So far, I've tried creating a file, config/intializers/date_formats.rb, with the following code

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%A, %e %b %Y"
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%A %e %b %Y"
```

but nothing happens when I add

```
event.mytimeobject.to_formatted_s(:default)
```

I've also tried

```
event.mytimeobject.strftime(%A,%e %b %Y)
```

but I'm getting errors with that as well

Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot your quotation marks: `event.mytimeobject.strftime("%A, %e %b %Y")`

Comment: Oh wow, I'm embarrassed. Thank you >.<